# Stored procedure doesn't show result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a stored procedure (to be used in SSRS) that has parameters whose values are more than one. When I execute this stored procedure in SSMS by providing the values for that parameter, SP doesn't return any result. It should return more than 1 rows

Below is the SP given

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_tst_CSENG_JulieCapitalHours]
        @StartDate DATETIME ,
        @EndDate DATETIME ,
        @ProjHomeGrp NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @ProjHier NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS  
BEGIN
    SELECT  [Capital Project] ,
                    [Capital Task] ,
                    ResourceName ,
                    ProjectName ,
                    [Project Home Group] ,
                    ActualWork ,
                    TimeByDay ,
                    ResourceStandardRate ,
                    ActualWork * ResourceStandardRate AS Dollars ,
                    [Project Hierarchy]
    FROM [IR.CapOnly]
    WHERE ( TimeByDay >= @StartDate )
      AND ( [Project Home Group] IN ( @ProjHomeGrp ) )
      AND ( TimeByDay <= @EndDate )
      AND ( ActualWork > 0 )
      AND ( [Project Hierarchy] IN ( @ProjHier ) )
    ORDER BY ProjectName ,
             ResourceName
END
```

You can see that in the where clause, Project Home Group (`@ProjHomeGrp`) and Project Hierarchy (`@ProjHier`) are the parameters, whose value when supplied (more than 1) SP returns zero values.

The value that I'm passing are:

```
Start Date: 1/1/2011 
End Date: 12/31/2012
@ProjHomeGrp : PHG1,PHG2,PHG3,PHG4,PHG5,PHG6,PHG7
@ProjHier: PROH1, PROH2, PROH3
```

Let me know for any questions!

Comment: may I know is this problem with the multiple values for Project Home Group (@ProjHomeGrp) and Project Hierarchy (@ProjHier) parameters seperated by comma delimited. Are you facing the same problem with the single values for the Project Home Group (@ProjHomeGrp) and Project Hierarchy (@ProjHier) parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Oded said, table valued parameters are the way to go. However, here is a solution based on dynamic sql, with all the problems that might imply...

```
create procedure [dbo].[sp_tst_CSENG_JulieCapitalHours]
        @StartDate datetime ,
        @enddate datetime ,
        @ProjHomeGrp nvarchar(MAX) ,
        @ProjHier nvarchar(MAX)
    as  
begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(max)
    declare @paramDefs nvarchar(max)

    select @sql = N'select  [Capital Project] ,
            [Capital Task] ,
            ResourceName ,
            ProjectName ,
            [Project Home Group] ,
            ActualWork ,
            TimeByDay ,
            ResourceStandardRate ,
            ActualWork * ResourceStandardRate AS Dollars ,
            [Project Hierarchy]
    from    [IR.CapOnly]
    where   ( TimeByDay >= @StartDate )
            and ( [Project Home Group] IN (' + @ProjHomeGrp + ') )
            and ( TimeByDay <= @EndDate) )
            and ( ActualWork > 0 )
            and ( [Project Hierarchy] IN ( ' + @ProjHier + ' ) )
    order by ProjectName, ResourceName'

    select @paramDefs = N'@StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime'

    exec sp_executesql @sql, @paramDefs, @StartDate = @StartDate, @EndDate =  @EndDate
end
```

Comment: Thanks @David Brabant. I applied your query into SP and it ran Ok. But when I'm passing parameters (as before I did) I am still not getting any value (0 rows)

Comment: There was a typo in the sql statement I copy/pasted here (StartDat instead of StartDate). Check the statement. Also check the @sql string in SQL Server debugger to verify it is correct. Copy paste that string in a new session to verify it gives the results you expect.

Comment: You may be opening the door to SQL Injection with this.

Comment: That's why I added my warning: "with all the problems that might imply..."

Answer (score 1):

This looks wrong:

```
[Project Home Group] IN ( @ProjHomeGrp )
```

You can't use `IN` with an `NVARCHAR` type and expect to be able to use set based operations on it directly.

This may be closer to what you are looking for:

```
[Project Home Group] = @ProjHomeGrp
```

And (guessing here, from your use of `IN`) if you are using the `NVARCHAR(MAX)` parameters as delimited text (say integers with commas as separators), there are better ways - you should be using [Table Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) for such  thing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have just updated my question with what values I'm passing. Can you help me here?

Comment: @SmithPascalJr. - Help? I believe TVPs, as I answered are the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Create procedure like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Show_Sproceduresome
   AS 
 Begin
    select points,coursename,c.type from OfferType o,Courses c,Candidate cd, CourseOffer
     where name = 'Francisco' 
     and o.OfferId = co.OfferId 
     and co.CourseId = c.CourseId 
     and co.UCASNumber = cd.UCASNumber
 End
```

Execute the procedure like:

```
exec Sproceduresome
```

Does not display results or out put